# SQL Query to Sum Values in the First Instance of an ID within the Dataset

Tags: sql

Trying to write a SQL query for database analysis.  I am using Microsoft SQL server.

I need to extract the first instance of a PanelsubID in the database and do some basic analytics.
The below query I am trying is using all instances of PanelsubID in the summation.

This is what I am working with so far, I have a few different variations, each puts out the same results.

Below Almost gets me the results I need but it is summing all the instances of the panelsubID and I need it to only use the first instance.

```
WITH FirstInstance AS (
    SELECT PanelSubID, 
           MIN(column1) AS Min_Column1,
           MAX(column1) AS Max_Column1,
           MIN(column2) AS Min_Column2,
           MAX(column2) AS Max_Column2,
           COUNT(column1) AS Count_Column1,
           COUNT(column2) AS Count_Column2,
           SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column2
    FROM myTable
    WHERE BatchID = 'testBatch'
    GROUP BY PanelSubID
)
SELECT UP.PanelSubID,
       FI.Min_Column1,
       FI.Max_Column1,
       FI.Min_Column2,
       FI.Max_Column2,
       FI.Count_Column1,
       FI.Count_Column2,
       FI.Count_Zero_Column1,
       FI.Count_Zero_Column2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PanelSubID
    FROM myTable
    WHERE BatchID = 'testBatch'
) UP
JOIN FirstInstance FI ON UP.PanelSubID = FI.PanelSubID
GROUP BY UP.PanelSubID
ORDER BY UP.PanelSubID;
```

This SQL Code gets me the right results but only 1 panelsubID at a time

```
`WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT *
 , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY someColumn ORDER BY PanelSubID)
 FROM myTable
 WHERE BatchID = 'testBatch'
 AND PanelSubID = '1234'
)
Select
       MIN(column1) AS Min_Column1,
       MAX(column1) AS Max_Column1,
       MIN(column2) AS Min_Column2,
       MAX(column2) AS Max_Column2,
       COUNT(column1) AS Count_Column1,
       COUNT(column2) AS Count_Column2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column2
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1L`
```

Comment: Please update your question with the DDL for your table, enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios and the result you are expecting. What’s your definition of “the first instance of a PanelsubID”?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, however I managed to find the solution, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  Appreciate anyone who took a look into this question.  All I needed really was to add a second column as a parameter for the Partition function.

```
WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT *
 , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY someColumn, PanelSubID ORDER BY PanelSubID)
 FROM myTable
 WHERE BatchID = 'testBatch'
)
Select
       MIN(column1) AS Min_Column1,
       MAX(column1) AS Max_Column1,
       MIN(column2) AS Min_Column2,
       MAX(column2) AS Max_Column2,
       COUNT(column1) AS Count_Column1,
       COUNT(column2) AS Count_Column2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Zero_Column2
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY PanelSubID
ORDER BY PanelSubID
```